# How to handle mutiple tab selections via selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

Currently im struggling to click on the second tab, of a multiple tab button.

When a user click on the first option: 'Accept' they then can select the second option which will then get presented to them being 'Decline'.

The following code it able to click on the 'Accept' option however unable to click on the 'Decline' option, it seems the button closes the 'Decline' panel as soon as it click on the 'Accept' option.

```
        WebElement acceptOrDeclineTabToggle = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("((//a[contains(@id, 'classbookingtabs:upcomingSessions')])[1]/following-sibling::*)[1]"));
        WebElement declineButton = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text()='Decline'])[1]"));
        JavaScriptUtils javaScriptUtils = new JavaScriptUtils();
        javaScriptUtils.click(acceptOrDeclineTabToggle);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        javaScriptUtils.click(declineButton);
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any ideas? I have also tried to use Actions but it doesn't seem to resolve my issue.

Comment: Does the `Decline` option show only after clicking `...` once `Accept` is selected? Can you please share the html of that div or parent element including tag `a`.

Comment: @supputuri thats correct it only shows once a user click on the ... option.

Comment: can you please share html for `Decline`